# show views of controller from another storyboard correctly using iCarousel

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, carousel

I have got 2 storyboards (lets say SB1 and SB2), in SB1 there is an implementation of an iCarousel as so:

```
import UIKit
import iCarousel

class VotingViewController: UIViewController, iCarouselDataSource, iCarouselDelegate { 
    @IBOutlet var carouselView: iCarousel!

    let SB2 = UIStoryboard(name: "SB2Name", bundle: Bundle.main)

    var itemsArray:[VC2] = []
    var vc2: VC2!
    var somenumber:Int = 20

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        vc2 = SB2.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC2_Page") as! VC2
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        itemsArray = [VC2](repeating: vc2, count: somenumber.count)

        carouselView.type = .rotary
        carouselView.reloadData()
    }

// MARK: - iCarousel
    func numberOfItems(in carousel: iCarousel) -> Int {
        return somenumber
    }

    func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAt index: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
        let appVC = itemsArray[index]

        self.addChildViewController(appVC)
        appVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

        appVC.view.frame = carouselView.frame

        return appVC.view
    }

    func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, valueFor option: iCarouselOption, withDefault value: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        if (option == .spacing) {
            return value * 1.1
        }
        return value
    }
}
```

I want to use iCarousel from @NickLockwood to show views from Storyboard SB2 but get some strange carousel view, only one of the views is shown in carousel.

I am forced to use different storyboard's controller view. Don't post answers where I just put everything in one storyboard. Thx.

maybe someone knows what i am missing?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer which I came up with is in the link

https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel/issues/808

Answer (score 0):

you need to tell iCarousel how many items to show by implementing something like:

```
  func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, valueFor option: iCarouselOption, withDefault value: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {

    switch option {
    case .spacing:
        return value * 1.0
    case .wrap:
        return 1
    case .visibleItems:
        return 7
    default:
        return value
    }

}
```